# Fade out menu doesn't work in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fadeout

I used this script in my website. But it doesn't work in IE8 or lower versions.
Is it possible to work perfectly in all browsers?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web/upload/js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if(scrollTop != 0)
                    $('#header').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},400);
                else    
                    $('#header').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},400);
            });

            $('#header').hover(
                function (e) {
                    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if(scrollTop != 0){
                        $('#header').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},400);
                    }
                },
                function (e) {
                    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if(scrollTop != 0){
                        $('#header').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},400);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: hmmm, well, first off, there was lot not supported by IE8 in 1.3, have you tried updating your jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Actually since you are using jquery it take care of cross browser issues in-case of opacity so I think you have to do nothing.

try using:

`$("yourid").css({ opacity: 0.0 }).animate( {opacity:0}, 400);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in jQuery 1.3.2, you can get further details here [Jquery Bugs](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5033), Try to use updated jquery.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js

Comment: My pleasure :) If it helps you mark it correct so it helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this at top just after doc ready:

because you are using jquery 1.3 use this code

```
$(function() {
    $('#header').css("opacity","0");
   // then all your code
```